# How far do I need to sticky-jump for the 'Highland Fling' achievement?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2, tf2-demoman

I've been trying to earn the achievement 'Highland Fling' by sticky-jumping as far as I can, however the description is a little vague as to how far I need to travel:

[image: Highland Fling Achievement: Sticky jump a really long way...]

So how far exactly do I need to travel? Is there a place/map that makes earning this achievement easier?

Comment: This video helped me to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvJkQ69NiTs You pretty much need to jump an entire map and die because of the fall damage.

Comment: @mhsjlw - Cool thanks :). Just earned it on Dustbowl from the Blu Spawn corner over to the cliff wall :) Do you want to flesh that out into a full answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve the Highland fling is to jump across koth_badlands. You can do this by placing stickies here (make sure you don't place too little or too much, 3 stickies is good):

[image: where to place stickies]

And then you can step forward a little bit past the sickies and detonate to propel yourself across the map so that you hit an invisible wall.

Enjoy the achievement!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [**the video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvJkQ69NiTs) provided by mhsjlw, I was able to finally figure out how to earn this achievement. My problem was I wasn't using enough sticky bombs and thus wasn't getting enough force to propel myself the distance.

Unlike the video, I earned it on Dustbowl, by flinging from the top-right entrance to BLU's spawn, to the cliffs in the diagonally opposite corner:

[image: BLU spawn entrance]

Place your stickies about here, and aim for the cliffs. Remember to jump and crouch midair.
[image: Placing Stickies, aiming for cliffs]

It took me a while to get an action shot:
[image: Flying!]

The achievement should unlock just as you hit the cliffs. (I didn't even die!)

Comment: Awesome! I was told that you needed to die to get the achievement from fall damage but I guess not! Unfortunately I wasn't paying attention to my notifications but I would have been happy to fully answer the question :)

Comment: @mhsjlw please do! I added mine for reference, if you write an answer I'll accept yours :-)